# Is there any way I can get a list of all possible responses from the google vision api?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using the google cloud vision api to analyze pictures. Is there a list of all the possible responses for the labelAnnotations method?

Answer (score 0):

The [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#annotateimageresponse) of Vision API gives an overview of all the possible JSON responses for the different image annotation requests.

The `labelAnnotation` request returns a generic [EntityAnnotation response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#EntityAnnotation), you can find the JSON representation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#EntityAnnotation), also containing more information about the JSON representation of BoundingPoly, LocationInfo and Property:

```
{
  "mid": string,
  "locale": string,
  "description": string,
  "score": number,
  "confidence": number,
  "topicality": number,
  "boundingPoly": {
    object(BoundingPoly)
  },
  "locations": [
    {
      object(LocationInfo)
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      object(Property)
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: I think the question was about whether they can have a list of the possible label/entity values (`mid`s) that can be in a response, which is asking for a list of all entries in Google's Knowledge Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking whether you can get a look at the list of possible labels/entities that the Cloud Vision API will detect. If that's the case, the short answer is **no**, not in any manageable way.

The more complicated answer is *sort of*, since most labels will have a property for the knowledge graph entry (e.g., `{desc: 'dog', mid: '/m/0bt9lr'}`). This means that you can look-up more information about the label/entity using the [Knowledge Graph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/).

While you can't "store a copy" of Google's Knowledge Graph as a list of choices in a drop-down on a page, you can use the API to do a look-up after the Vision API responds with an ID.